# Override jqm css style for disabled form elements

Tags: css, forms, jqmobi

The default style for disabled form elements in jqm makes them vary hard to read

I've tried adding a style to change the text color eg.

```
.ui-disabled{
    color: red;
}
```

This does change the color of the text (to a light red not the default) but there seems to be a semi-transparent layer over the top which I can't find in the DOM?

Ideally I'm just looking for a way to drop the transparency of the overlay

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opacity is set to .5 on disabled elements, so if you set opacity:1 it should be fine

```
.ui-disabled{
    color:red;
    opacity:1 !important;
}
```